# What is the origin of the Hardhat project?

Tags: hardhat, hardhat-deploy

Hardhat seems like a nice toolset and it is referenced by other projects I follow.

I would like to know more about the origin of this project.

1. When did Nomic Labs LLC create Hardhat?
2. It appears to be funded by Ethereum Foundation, what was the funding amount and was there any other funding?
3. How does this project make money?

This will help me to truck the project more and I like to know these things before I recommend a project publicly.